# is the default constructor is declaring is compulsary?

Tags: java

We all Know that the JVM provides us a default constructor in the every java program.

But if we declare any other type of constructor then it does not provide the any type of default constructor.

So, my question is that is it compulsory to declare default constructor when we declare any other type of constructor in our program.

If YES then explain Why?
If NO then also explain Why?

Give the Solution with proper suitable example.

Comment: This looks more like an interview question, specially with the wordings *If YES then explain Why ? If NO then also explain Why? Give the Solution with proper suitable example.*

Comment: why not trust the tutorial : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: it's only been 4 hours. Anyway, they are not obliged to accept any of the answers if they don't think it answers the question well enough.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy : Then provide a better answer

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: what is the relation between not accepting an answer and asking me to write my own answer? This is about the OP, not me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to create the default constructor, but it is good practice to create the default constructor.
If your class is to be reused then not creating the default constructor will limit the re-usability of your class.
Like if a class is extending that class, then the derived class must have an explicit super call.

consider the following example:-

```
class Base
{
    public Base(int x){
        //some statements
    }
    /*
       some methods
    */
}

class Derived
{
    // only one of the following will be used
    public Derived(){  // This will cause a compile-time error
      //some statements
    }
    public Derived(){  // This will work fine
     //some statements
        super(x);
    }
    /*
      some methods
    */
}
```

The reason behind this is, if the base class do not have default constructor than derived class must call the appropriate super() in all its constructor declarations. But if we have a default constructor in base class then the call to super() is not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not compulsory at all. There are loads of classes with no default constructor, and there's nothing stopping you from writing your own.  One that springs to mind is `java.awt.Color`.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the default constructor depends on the business requirement and technically its not compulsory.

If you want a class to be initialized only with a set of parameters, then you can skip the default constructor, which indeed forces you -- to give the required values to create the object

For instance,

```
public class ClassA {

String name;
ClassA(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

For the above class, if you want to do,

```
ClassA obj = new ClassA();
```

This is not possible as there is not default constructor.

```
ClassA obj = new ClassA("name");
```

The above is the only way to create object, as name is the parameter should be given.

If you want both to be created, add default constructor as

```
ClassA() {}
```

Which provides way to create the object with out name.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not cumpolsory.

```
class Dog {

Dog(String name)
{
 system.out.println("Dog :" + name);
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 Dog d = new Dog("dollar"); // works fine
 Dog d2 = new Dog() // error , no default constructor defined for Dog
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is that is it compulsory to declare default
>   constructor when we declare any other type of constructor in our
>   program.

No, It's not necessary to have a default constructor.

> If NO then also explain Why ?

Default Constructor will be provided by Compiler, only if you don't defined any no argument Constructor. But, Keep in mind the following, Check mode from [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)

> **8.8.9. Default Constructor**
>
> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default
>   constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is
>   implicitly declared.
>
> If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the
>   default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default
>   constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no
>   arguments.
>
> It is a compile-time error if a default constructor is implicitly
>   declared but the superclass does not have an accessible constructor
>   (§6.6) that takes no arguments and has no throws clause.

Comment: The default constructor isn't provided by the JVM at all. It's provided by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not compulsory! 
But then if you dont have a default constructor(No-argument constructor) and if you want the to create the object of your class in this form

```
A ref = new A();
```

then you might not be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not necessary.

let me explain why this is not necessary 
                  The question which you've asked is seems like constructor overloading.

```
         If you create an or many parameterized constructor in java then you do need need to be worried for the default constructor.
```

Basically constructor is used to initialize the instance variables or class members or for performing the preliminary tasks and if you have already done with this by using the another constructor then there is no need for another but you can do if you want.

public class base {
    int a;

```
public base(int x)
{
    this.a=x;
    System.out.println(x);
}
public base()
{
    System.out.println("abc");
}

public static void main(String []a)
{
    base b=new base();
    b=new base(4);
}
```

}

The output is :-

abc
4